# Generic List Using Vectors in C++

Tags: c++, templates, vector, typename

I'm relatively new to programming and I did really well in my introductory class. However, as we are starting to get into the more advanced concepts of C++, I'm becoming more and more lost. I'm having a problem with a lab assignment, I hope you guys can help!

> Write a generic list class called GenericList. The class should use a vector and be able to >be created with any type name. The class should have the following members:
>
> - A simple constructor
> - add(item) - add the item to the list
> - grabSmallest() - find, return and remove the smallest item in the list

Here is what I have so far, I believe it is at least set up correctly:

***EDIT***

This is what I have after the corrections that have been suggested, I've ran into a different problem now, though. Here is the revised code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class GenericList
{
public:
    GenericList();
    void add(T value);
    T grabSmallest();

private:
    vector<T> listVector;
};

template<typename T>
GenericList<T>::GenericList()
{
}

template<typename T>
void GenericList<T>::add(T value)
{
    listVector.push_back(value);
}

template<typename T>
T GenericList<T>::grabSmallest()
{
    int smallest = listVector[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < listVector.size(); i++)
    {
        if (listVector[i] < smallest)
        {
        smallest = listVector[i];
        }
    }
}

int main (){
    GenericList<int> myList;
    myList.add(10);
    myList.add(5);
    myList.add(20);
    myList.add(15);

    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        cout << myList.grabSmallest() << " ";
}
```

I'm now having problems with my for loop in the grab function. Apparently, the compiler is putting random numbers into the vector.

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: 1. need a ``return smallest`` in your ``grabSmallest``; 2. ``T smallest`` instead of ``int smallest``; 3. why you need an iteration of ``cout`` if you want the smallest???

Comment: My instructor wrote main, I just have to make main work without editing it.

Comment: I don't see what's wrong.  It looks OK to me, but that doesn't mean there isn't a problem.  Can you please post the output from running it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Where is the `last`?
2. Even you have the `last`,

   ```
   template<typename T>
   void GenericList<T>::add(const T &value)
   {
       listVector[last++] = value; // <- should it be last++ or ++last?
   }
   ```

   or do you mean:

   ```
   template<typename T>
   void GenericList<T>::add(const T &value)
   {
       listVector.push_back(value)
   }
   ```

   BTW, With `vector`, you dont need the `last` field. It's kept in the `vector`: `  `vector.size()`.  But why wrap `vector` when you could just use vector directly?
3. if you want the just want the smallest, `priority_queue` will do.

Comment: I'm not really too familiar with how vectors work, I wasn't even aware you could just use push_back there. I thought you would have to copy it over to the vector like you would with an array. Even so, how do I get the grabSmallest function to read from the vector and sort the members?

Comment: @ChrisWillis ``vector<int> a;`` could be access like an array like ``a[0] = 3``. For your reference: [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)

Answer (score 0):

As gongzhitaao said, that line is not liking you because you never declare `last` and thus the compiler doesn't know what to do with it.  as they said, you need to use `push_back` to solve that problem.

But you also need to solve another problem: what happens if they don't use `int` as their type?  What if they want the "least" member of a custom class?  You need to change this:

```
vector<int> listVector;
```

to this

```
vector<T> listVector;
```

So that the `vector` picks up the custom type that the template parameter `T` is specifying.

For `grabSmallest` I suggest you use some type of search to determine which element is the smallest, such as picking the first element, then looping through after that to see if each subsequent one is smaller or not.  If it is, take that as your value, and loop.  If not, just keep going.  Whichever is left over at the end is smallest.  But remember to use `T` as your type all the way through.  Sorting it on every insert isn't necessary with this method.

As this is homework I didn't want to give you 100% of the answer with code, but hopefully the preceding paragraph is enough to get you going.

Edit: figured it out.  Try www.codepad.org and run your code through it.

Basically, two errors in your grabSmallest() method.

1. It should be `T smallest = listVector[0]` not `int`.  You should also have a "guard" that returns a default value (or throws an exception) if the list is empty.
2. grabSmallest() is supposed to return a value, but you forgot to.  So your compiler is apparently way too forgiving, and didn't flag that as an error.  Put `return smallest` as the last line of the method, just after the `for` loop.

Comment: @ChrisWillis Yes, right. Trying some introduction to cpp like [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/) will solve all your small problems.

Comment: So, couldn't I just something like:

    template<typename T>
T GenericList<T>::grabSmallest()
{
    int smallest = listVector.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < listVector.length; i++)
        if (listVector[i] < smallest) {
            smallest = listVector[i];
        }
}